# LibGDX/Java development: Passing Game objects between classes

Tags: java, libgdx, screen, dispose

I am creating an android application composed of three screens and a game object that is passed between them.

- A MenuScreen that is only used when the game is started. This makes no change to the GameObj and simply sets the screen to the GameScreen.
- The GameScreen where the player dodges falling blocks while the GameObj.timer measures the time the player is alive. When the player collides with a falling object, the screen is set to the EndScreen.
- The EndScreen lists the time the player was alive by accessing the GameObj.Timer and has a button to set the screen back to the GameScreen.

The information is passed from the GameScreen to the EndScreen properly the first time, but when the Reset button is pressed and the screen is set to GameScreen, the timer is NOT reset back to 0 and the blocks from the previous game are still present.

Initially I had used GameObj.setScreen(new GameScreen(this)); but this creates a leak because the previous GameScreen is never deleted.

I am wondering if there is a way in LibGDX to dispose the entire screen (rather than just the textures) and create a new one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all: Don't use the `Game` class for the timer. The `Timer` does belong to the `MenuScreen` and the `EndScreen` only. So you can pass the `Timer` instead of the `Game` object. The `Game` object should be used only for changing the `Screen`. To your question: Every `Screen` has a `hide` a `show` and a `dispose` method. `hide` gets called for the current `Screen`, when you switch the `Screen` to another. There you should reset the `GameWorld`, if it is the `GameScreen` and the `Timer`, if it is the `EndScreen`. In the `show` method you can recreate the `GameWorld`

Comment: Who you don't make a class like GlobalStuffs and add a public static object so you can use it anywhere you want?